# How hide button "Create invoice" but based in condition ? (Odoo 11)

Tags: python, xml, odoo

there really I am blocked, I want to hide the button "Create invoice" but based on a condition, my condition is if order line has services, the button is hidden. I created a field and a function but in the end there's always an error that the field doesn't exist in the model, **here's my code :**

**Error :**

> Field 'hide_invoice' used in attributes must be present in view but is missing

**My field and function (Python) :**

```
from odoo import api, fields, models,_


class SaleOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    hide_invoice = fields.Boolean(compute="_hide_button_invoice", string="",)


    @api.multi
    @api.depends('tasks_count')
    def _hide_button_invoice(self):
        for order in self:
            if order.tasks_count > 0:
                order.hide_invoice = True
            elif order.tasks_count == 0:
                order.hide_invoice = False
```

**My XML (I see on the form that it works) :**

```
<odoo>
<record id="button_invoice_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">sale.order.button.create.form</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='partner_id']" position="before">
                <field name ="hide_invoice"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
</record>
</odoo>
```

**The button then i want to hide it :**

```
<record id="sale_order_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">sale.order.form</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//group[@name='sale_pay']/field[@name='invoice_status']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible" eval="False"/>
        </xpath>
        <xpath expr="//button[@name='action_quotation_send']" position="before">
            <button name="%(sale.action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv)d" string="Create Invoice"
                type="action" class="btn-primary"
                attrs="{'invisible': [('invoice_status', '!=', 'to invoice')]}"/>
            <button name="%(sale.action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv)d" string="Create Invoice"
                type="action" context="{'default_advance_payment_method': 'percentage'}"
                attrs="{'invisible': ['|','|',('hide_invoice', '=', True),('invoice_status', '!=', 'no'), ('state', '!=', 'sale')]}"/>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Read the documentation or go through the tutorials sites before asking simple questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to display field on header level to handle these.

Like do following code before your button declared.

```
<field name='hide_invoice' invisible='1'/>
```

And remove it before partner_id field.

**EDIT**

Can you try with following xml code:

```
<record id="sale_order_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">sale.order.form</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//group[@name='sale_pay']/field[@name='invoice_status']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible" eval="False"/>
        </xpath>
        <xpath expr="//button[@name='action_quotation_send']" position="before">
            <button name="%(sale.action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv)d" string="Create Invoice"
                type="action" class="btn-primary"
                attrs="{'invisible': [('invoice_status', '!=', 'to invoice')]}"/>
            <field name="hide_invoice" invisible="1"/>
            <button name="%(sale.action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv)d" string="Create Invoice"
                type="action" context="{'default_advance_payment_method': 'percentage'}"
                attrs="{'invisible': ['|','|',('hide_invoice', '=', True),('invoice_status', '!=', 'no'), ('state', '!=', 'sale')]}"/>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Are you sure, that you have to differentiate between header, body and footer in form views?

Comment: @CZoellner It will be based on where we use that field. In short field should be declare before use it, like in attrs. It doesn't matter between header, body and footer. I have one module which will hide button for first time and afterwards, it visible. Please correct me.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work, i configure : ``<xpath expr="//header" position="inside">
    <field name ="hide_invoice" invisible="1"/>
   </xpath>``

Comment: @NabilTaleb Can you share your full updated xml file code in your question.

Comment: Same thing, now it's: > Field "Hide_invoice' don't exist